# amazon aws how many m1.small spot request can i create in one region by default

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In amazon aws how many m1.small spot request can i create in one region by default
when i see in Instances limit it shows me some thing like

```
    Spot Instance requests default  Request limit increase
```

but currently i am running 36 m1.small
and it gives me an error while creating new spot request

```
   MaxSpotInstanceCountExceeded
```

so my question is  how many spot request can i make of one particular type (eg.m1.small or m1.large)
or how does amazon aws calculate MaxSpotInstanceCountExceeded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MaxSpotInstanceCount` is the hard limit of on number of spot instances that you can launch irrespective of their type. the default is 5. However, in your case it seems to be 36.

You can request AWS to increase the limit  by filling out this form: https://aws.amazon.com/support/createCase?type=service_limit_increase&serviceLimitIncreaseType=ec2-instances

For any other doubts, please reach out to their support: https://aws.amazon.com/support